# Inflate 2 layouts (1 main, 1 additional)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So i have 2 java files buyClothes.java and searchClothes.java.
At buyClothes by java the layout that is being used is : R.layout.bClothes and at searchClothes the layout that is being used is : R.layout.sClothes

In bClothes there is an Edittext which is being used in buyClothes, in searchClothes i would like to use that Edittext aswell. From what i understood from this website and information i then have to inflate it in searchClothes to be able to use it. I have done that this way..

```
View view;
LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater)   getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.bClothes, null);
EditText testEdit = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
testEdit.setHint("testhint");
```

Now the application doesn't crash but i don't see the hint on the testEdit file, as if it is being ignored or nothing can be done with the view, or i have a slight feeling that te view might return null or something.

Do you have any hints on this matter?

Comment: try to set hint directly in layout.

Comment: I don't want that, i want it in the second layout. set hint is just used to test here if there is some reaction from the inflated layout. Apparently there is not.

Comment: You can include edittext xml in you main xml layout. <include layout="@layout/xtz"/>

Comment: You have the same result when you try to set the text (.setText())? only the hint doesn't work?

Comment: @Rami both don't work,

Comment: @Yashdeep Patel, that chould be an option but i think it would ruin my actual layout

Comment: @zakbennani refer my below answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that inflated view into your main layout or where ever you want.

Just take an example of Linear layout

```
LinearLayout layout  = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.edit_layout);
layout.addView(view);
```

This may work for you. I hope i got your question right.

Comment: I checked it out mate but it didn't produce the effect i wanted

Comment: @zakbennani what issue you are facing? And which effect you want?